# Make a picture cover the whole cell in foundation zurb

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation-5

I am trying to make some picture fully cover the cells in a foundation zurb. I keep getting some margins in the cells. Is there a way to avoid this? The pictures are a little bit less in width than the cells' width.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <img src="pic1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
          <img src="pic2.png" width="100%">
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 columns">
          <img src="assets/pic4.png">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set to your `.column, .columns` classes `padding: 0`.

```
.column, .columns {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Or better to create new class `padding-zero` for example, and set this class to every image which you want make without paddings.

Comment: but would I deal with the responsiveness thing as well?

Comment: @user3433309 what do you mean?

Comment: how would I deal with the responsiveness feature? I do not want the padding: 0 to be valid when the user is on the desktop for instance. I want the css to be validate only when the user is on the phone version

Comment: @user3433309 oh, use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) for this.

Comment: yeah yeah it was dump enough not to think about it. thnks I did it even before seeing your replay